# Reference modified column name from select statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to clean and dedupe email addresses in my DB. As such I have something similar to the following.

```
select rtrim(ltrim(replace(lower(Email), '"', '')))
from Users
where Email like '%_@_%.__%'
```

My problem being that the where statement still uses the unmodified email string, where I want it to use the email string after the replace and trims have been applied.

Note: I apply a lot more string modifications in my actual code but I shortened it as it was not relevant.

Comment: MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved... (And I find it hard to believe that code works with both.)

Comment: MySQL, thanks for picking up on that. Removed the server tag

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a column alias in a `WHERE` clause except in `HAVING` clause (due to the extension provided by MySQL). So, you will have to do it in a outer query like below, else the alternative provided in another answer.

```
select NewEmail
from(
select rtrim(ltrim(replace(lower(Email), '"', ''))) as NewEmail
from Users) xx
where NewEmail like '%_@_%.__%'
```

Comment: Not necessarily, look at my answer.

Comment: yes, you have provided an alternative where you are doing the same manipulation multiple times. it's no magic I believe

Comment: Twice, not multiple times, and its not a heavy or complex manipulation, so it doesn't really matter. Both query will take the same time, you just said "You will have to" so i corrected you:)

Comment: I prefer the derived table version, easier to code without errors, and so much easier/safer for someone else to adjust in the future. (And also ANSI SQL compliant, which the HAVING version isn't.)

Comment: in my actual code (as opposed to the heavily simplified example above) I'd need to do the manipulation over a dozen times. So copying the logic isn't feasible from clean code standpoint

Comment: @skeletalmonkey, that's why you should use a derived table or inline view expression. The example code have shown in answer. It's clean and not error prone.

Comment: Can you explain what the purpose of the 'xx' on the 4th line is?

Comment: @skeletalmonkey, xx is nothing but table alias which is needed to refer the inner query / inline table in outer query